# How to put the cursor in an input text if in another input text it was pressed Tab using onkeyup event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a function `f_onkeyup(this)` in which I do many things. I need inside that function `f_onkeyup()` to get the key released in order to validate if it is a <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and if it is a <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I have to focus in another input text. But I need to do all that inside the `f_onkeyup()` function.

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="nom" onkeyup='f_onkeyup(this)' />
  <input type="text" id="age" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script>


     function f_onkeyup(field){

       $( document ).on( 'keypress', function ( e ) { 
         //I don't know how to get the keyreleased               
         if ( e.keyCode == 9 ) { //Tab key code
           document.getElementById("age").focus();//put cursor on age input
             }
       });

     }



  </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) { 

     if ( e.which== 9 ) { //Tab key code
     $('#age').focus();//put cursor on age input
         }
   });
```

Use above Jquery inside your function.it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
1) you need to bind the event with the input.
2) and then you may modify the input tag.

```
<script>
 $("body").on( 'keydown',"#nom". function ( e ) { 

 if ( e.which== 9 ) { //Tab key code
 $('#age').focus();//put cursor on age input
     }
});
```

```
<input type="text" id="nom" onkeyup='f_onkeyup(this)' />
```